# How set up a new disk device /dev/vdb?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, storage, lvm

I'm using KVM to boot the VM.
I'm starting with RHEL and I would like to know how do I create a new /dev/vdb?

```
[root@master dev]# lsblk
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                   11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
vda                  252:0    0   40G  0 disk 
├─vda1               252:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─vda2               252:2    0   39G  0 part 
  ├─rhel_master-root 253:0    0   35G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel_master-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

my /etc/fstab file.

```
[root@master dev]# cat /etc/fstab 

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sat May 12 12:24:58 2018
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/rhel_master-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=<omitted> /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel_master-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying makes no sense.

VDB would be the second virtual disk, so to get it you would set up another disk device in the VM configuration - but anything which relies on a hard coded device name is suspect.

Comment: Very sorry for the bad question.
Could you help on how can I set up another disk device in the VM configuration?

Comment: Lots of ways, but one way would be to open virt-manager (on the host of-course). select the VM, click the "i" (information) button, add hardware, storage and add another disk device.  Make sure the device type is "Virtio"